# locating xpath with starts with and ends with

Tags: selenium, xpath

Following xpath I have copied from the browser(inspect)

```
# // *[ @ id = "customize-coverage--customize-your-quote--propertyDamage-1--info-title"]
```

I am trying to read the element but its just not able to locate it with the follwoing xpath

Is there anyway I can locate the above element by selenium? Please help. I am not sure why the belwo is not working to locate the web element by driver

```
return self.page_element(By.XPATH,
                                 '//*[starts-with(@id,"customize-coverage--customize-your-quote--propertyDamage-") and ends-with(@id,"-info-title")]/span').text
```

I tried to use contains and regex also. Nothing seems to work.

Note: I am using python

Comment: Share HTML for the same

Answer (score 0):

`ends-with()` requires XPath 2.0, and although that's now nearly 14 years old, Selenium doesn't implement it yet. You have to use a combination of `substring()` and `string-length()`.